# Executing tasks by fully qualified name in a gradle build still evaluates build.gradle file from other non-dependent modules

Tags: gradle

I have a multi-module gradle project

```
Root project 'store'
+--- Project ':frontend'
\--- Project ':backend'
```

`backend` module is not-dependent on `frontend`.

`frontend` build.gradle reads an env variable into a global variable like this

```
val mock: String = System.getenv("MOCK")
```

I build `backend` module by its *fully qualified name*. Still the build fails with the following error:

```
root@cb58dcee6559:/app# ./gradlew :backend:build -x test

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/app/frontend/build.gradle.kts' line: 11

* What went wrong:
getenv("mock") must not be null
```

From this link, https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/intro_multi_project_builds.html#sec:executing_tasks_by_name I note that

> Gradle looks down the hierarchy, starting with the current dir, for tasks with the given name and executes them. One thing is very important to note. Gradle always evaluates every project of the multi-project build and creates all existing task objects. Then, according to the task name arguments and the current directory, Gradle filters the tasks which should be executed. Because of Gradle’s cross project configuration, every project has to be evaluated before any task gets executed.

But the above is for **Executing tasks by name**

Is that true also when building specific modules and **Executing tasks by fully qualified name**?

I see this happening only on Linux (when building inside a docker container).

Doesn't happens on Windows (usual build from CLI)

```
docker run -it --rm -v gradle-cache:/root/.gradle -v $HOME/store:/app -w /app eclipse-temurin:17-jdk bash
```

Gradle version: gradle-8.0.1

and using gradle wrapper to run builds